# Как выбрать соседние предыдущий и последующий элемент стоящий от текущего на n-элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Внизу накидал пример.
Нужно выбрать элементы, которые отстоят от выбранного на +/- (3).
Знаю про `prev()` и `next()`, но они, я так понял, выбирают только непосредственно соседние

```
  <div class="sibling"></div>
  <div class="sibling"></div>
  <div class="sibling"></div>
  <div class="sibling"></div>
  <div class="sibling current"></div>
  <div class="sibling"></div>
  <div class="sibling"></div>
  <div class="sibling"></div>
  <div class="sibling"></div>
  <div class="sibling"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не это ли ?

```
var prevElement = $('.sibling')[$('.sibling').index(this) - 3];
var nextElement = $('.sibling')[$('.sibling').index(this) + 3];
```

Comment: В первом селекторе разве не .current нужен?

Comment: @cheops, это я в пример привел. дальше автор по своему желанию решить что нужно

Answer (score 3):

Один из самых простых вариантов, это просто три раза подряд применить `next()` или `prev()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.current').next().next().next().html('Hello world!');
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling current"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Так вы подберетесь до третьего элемента, относительно текущего

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
  <head>
     ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling current"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling">Hello world!</div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Или как вариант воспользоваться методом `nextAll()`, который вернет все элементы после текущего, после чего можно вырезать нужный элемент при помощи `slice()`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.current').nextAll().slice(2, 3).html('Hello world!');
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling current"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
    <div class="sibling"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ну так то можно конечно)) но если мне нужно на 10 элементов?) уже как то не универсально

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов дополнил ответ